# How to pass new variable at one Canvas on javascript (No Jquery)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a problem with the canvas in javscript, I have a function that passes four values ​​to another function as soon as I click an image, each image passes different values, these values ​​I use to draw the chart with rectangles on the canvas, and it works! But as soon as I click another image, the rectangle values ​​of the graph do not change, they remain the same.
Where's the problem?

html

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

javascript

```
function gestoreInformazioni(){
    for (var i = 0; i < pizzeRegioni.length; i++){
        var pizza = pizzeRegioni[i];
        if( this.id === pizza.nome ){
            generaGrafico(pizza.prezzo, pizza.carboidrati, pizza.grassi, pizza.proteine);
        }
    }
}     
function generaGrafico(prezzo, carboidrati, grassi, proteine){
        try{
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle='rgb(255,255,0)';
        ctx.translate(0,200);
        ctx.fillRect(10,-(prezzo),40,150);
        ctx.fillRect(100,-(carboidrati),40,150);
        ctx.fillRect(200,-(grassi),40,150);
        ctx.fillRect(300,-(proteine),40,150);
    }catch(e){
        alert("generaGrafico " + e);
    }
}
```

init

```
nodoImgPizza = document.getElementsByClassName("img_pizza");
    for(var i = 0; i<nodoImgPizza.length; i++){
        nodoImgPizza[i].onclick = gestoreInformazioni;
    }
```

accociativeArray

```
var pizzeRegioni=[
    {
        nome:"Lardellata",
        regione:"Toscana",
        ingredienti :["pomodoro","mozzarella","lardo di Colonnata","ciliegini","porcini"],
        minX:134,
        minY:128,
        maxX:202,
        maxY:222,
        prezzo:6.50,
        carboidrati : 10,
        grassi : 15,
        proteine : 20,


    },
    {
        nome:"Senese",
        regione:"Toscana",
        ingredienti :["pomodoro","mozzarella","crudo di cinta senese","porcini"],
        minX:134,
        minY:128,
        maxX:202,
        maxY:222,
        prezzo:10,
        carboidrati : 100,
        grassi : 30,
        proteine : 40,

    }
];
```

Comment: Give us a whole example with clickable images, and show us how you call the function

Comment: The funcion parameter are take from anche a associative array, the Images are different pizzas generated with the same associative array

Comment: i've posted a new version whit all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To Re-Draw the same canvas over and over again, first you must **reset canvas** and then you can draw again.
See this snippet example:

```js
// on document ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

 function grafic(price, carbo, fat, protein){
  try{
   // Canvas Element
   var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
   var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

   // Reset Canvas
   ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 400);

   // Draw (Re-Draw) Canvas
   ctx.fillStyle='rgb(255,255,0)';
   ctx.translate(0,200);
   ctx.fillRect(10,-(price),40,150);
   ctx.fillRect(100,-(carbo),40,150);
   ctx.fillRect(200,-(fat),40,150);
   ctx.fillRect(300,-(protein),40,150);
  } catch(e){
   alert("generaGrafico " + e);
  }
 }
 
  // test buttons
 document.getElementById("a").addEventListener("click",function() {
  grafic(20, 40, 60, 80);
 }) 
 document.getElementById("b").addEventListener("click",function() {
  grafic(40, 20, 60, 100);
 }) 
 document.getElementById("c").addEventListener("click",function() {
  grafic(60, 40, 20, 10);
 }) 
 document.getElementById("d").addEventListener("click",function() {
  grafic(80, 100, 40, 20);
 })

});
```

```css
div {
 margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">Image A</div>
<div id="b">Image B</div>
<div id="c">Image C</div>
<div id="d">Image D</div>
<br/>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250"></canvas>
```

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much you Save my life

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo  "far" should be "fat"

ctx.fillRect(200,-(far),40,150);

I've slightly edited your code to demonstrate it works now.

```js
function grafic(price, carbo, fat, protein){
            try{
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.fillStyle='rgb(255,255,0)';
            ctx.translate(0,200);
            ctx.fillRect(10,-(price),40,150);
            ctx.fillRect(100,-(carbo),40,150);
            ctx.fillRect(200,-(fat),40,150);
            ctx.fillRect(300,-(protein),40,150);
        }catch(e){
            alert("generaGrafico " + e);
        }
    }
    
  grafic(4,4,4,4);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="250" style="border:1px solid; height 20px; min-widht: 200px"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yes work, but when i click on another Image the fillRect is the same (4,4,4,4), i want to chance It with different numer